# Android: onTouch events happen after scaling animation when touched outside

Tags: android, animation, touch-event

I have a layout that looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scaleType="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

"image" is full screen to start with. There is an onTouchListener set up for "image" which works fine. I then scale "image" with a ScaleAnimation (to about half size) and what I would expect to happen is that the onTouchListener would only pick up when the "image" is touched but it still fires for the whole screen and getX gets the same value as getRawX.

Is there any way of detecting whether I am inside the image bounds in onTouch? I thought about hard-coding the bounds according to the scale values but surely there must be a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can find width and height of image on screen as follows:

```
widthOnScreen = origWidth * scaleFactor
heightOnScreen = origHeight * scaleFactor
```

As you said "image is full screen to start with", `origWidth = viewWidth`, `origHeight = viewHeight` and scaleFactor is the total scale applied on the image until max/min.

```
matrix.getvalues(val);
```

Maintain left, top, right, bottom:

```
left=val[2]; 
right=val[Matrix.MSCALE_X]*actualWidth+val[2]; //actualWidth is image's actual width
top=val[5];
bottom=vals[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]*actualHeight+val[5];
```

Then `onTouch()`, check if your `event.getX()`, `getY()` are within these left, top, right, and bottom bounds.